# CK Editor Remove Focus on Page Load

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

On the page I have added CK Editor at the very bottom , every time the page loads it get focused on the CK Editor. I tried adding

```
config.startupFocus = false;
```

on the config.js file, but doesn't seems to be working. 
I also tried to focus any other element on page load, but since the CK Editor get loaded afterwards it got focused again.

I tried adding event listener on window frames and it doesn't worked either.

```
window.frames[0].document.addEventListener('load', function() { 
document.getElementById('email').focus(); 
});
```

Please suggest a way to remove focus from the CK Editor

Answer (score 0):

I dont know a lot about ckeditor but here is what I found on thier doc.
You can use the [FocusManager](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_focusManager.html).

```
var focusManager = new CKEDITOR.focusManager( editor );
focusManager.focus();//Focus
focusManager.remove();//Remove focus
```